# python code to check equality of i th and n-i-1 th terms

Tags: python

I wrote the following code in python to check equality of ith and n-i-1 th term. I get an error at the end of first for loop(at **:**).Please help

```
arr=[]
n=int(input("Enter the number of terms you want in the array"))


for i in range(0,n):
      a=int(input("Enter your number here"))
      arr.append(a)

for i in range(0,len(arr)):
    if arr[i]==arr[len(arr)-i-1]:
        print("The "+i+"th element and the "+len(arr)-i-1+"th element are equal" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic for this code snippet's second for loop is incorrect. Instead of calling `len()` on `a`, you should have called it on `arr`. So your second for loop should look like:

```
for i in range(0, len(arr)):
    if arr[i] == arr[len(arr) - i - 1]:
        print("The " + str(i) + "th element and the " + str(len(a) - i - 1) + "th element are equal")
```

Hope this helped!

***Edit:*** To accommodate for duplicate results, you would have to fix the number of iterations the for loop goes through. So the for loop would then look like this:

```
# Halve the number of iterations so it doesn't repeat itself
for i in range(0, len(arr) // 2):
    ...
```

***Edit 2:*** To figure out the proper ending for a specific numeral, try something similar to the following:

```
if not (10 < i < 14):
    if i % 10 == 1:
        print("st")
    # elif, etc...
    else:
        print("th")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering . i am still facing an error. i am getting redundant answers . like the 0th and 4th term are equal and 4th and 0th term are equal. How to remove this problem?

Comment: @joeylang Edited my response according to the new specs.

Comment: Your edit is flawed I believe. If the last two elements are equal, by halving the range, you will miss it.

Comment: thanks a lot. i wanted to ask one last thing .  i would like to display str(i) for i=1 or i=21 or i=31 with an ending of st rather than th. same for 2nd and 3rd. How do we do that?

Comment: @Flynsee I'm not sure if I'm following your logic - OP is essentially comparing `arr[i]` with `arr[-i-1]`.

Comment: @joeylang Consider posting a separate question at this point next time. This time I modified my answer - but remember, this is not to encourage you from keep doing it!

Comment: @Jerrybibo Oh my bad, I'm sorry you're perfectly right.

Comment: @joeylang Provided a hint.

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if arr[i]==arr[len(a)-i-1]:
         print("The "+i+"th element and the "+len(a)-i-1+"th element are equal" )
```

should be:

```
for i in range(0,len(arr)):
    if arr[i]==arr[len(arr)-i-1]:
         print("The "+i+"th element and the "+len(arr)-i-1+"th element are equal" )
```

Also you cannot convert int to str implicity:

```
print("The "+i+"th element and the "+len(arr)-i-1+"th element are equal" )
```

should be

```
print("The {}th element and the {}th element are equal".format(i,len(arr)-i-1))
```

Finally to get rid of the redundancy, replace:

```
if arr[i]==arr[len(arr)-i-1]:
```

with:

```
if arr[i]==arr[len(arr)-i-1] and len(arr)-i-1>i:
```